# Can't set ssl certificate on SIM800H module

Tags: ssl, arduino, at-command, sim800

I am trying to set a custom ssl certificate on a SIM800H module on my arduino (Adafruit FONA), in order to use it on mqtt with a secure TLS connection.
I am able to create and write the `C:\ca.crt` file in the module's filesystem, thanks to the AT-commands found in [this documentation](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2637/SIM800+Series_FS_Application+Note_V1.01.pdf).

However, I can't register it with the appropriate command `AT+SSLSETCERT=C:\ca.crt,ABC`. It returns an error.

I checked the file content by reading it back and it is correct. I also tried with various valid certificates, encrypted or not, it never works.
I also tried enabling the secure TCP with the command `AT+CIPSSL=1`, but this one also returns an error.
Adding random carriage returns at the top and/or bottom of the crt file didn't help.

The errors log are not helping, it just returns `Error`

Answer (score 0):

Probably your firmware doesn't support ssl.

If you search a newer one here:
https://simcom.ee/documents/?dir=

and flash it as is explained in http://www.raviyp.com/learn-how-to-update-the-firmware-of-your-sim800-modules/

you can make it

Answer (score 0):

AT+SSLSETCERT="C:\ca.crt","ABC"
you missed the double quote.